# Updateable Priority Queue

Tags: c++

Is there anything built into the C++ Standard Library that allows me to work in a priority queue/heap like data structure (i.e., can always pop the highest value from the list, can define how the highest value is determined for custom classes, etc.) but allows me to update the keys in the heap? I'm dealing with fairly simple data,  pairs to be exact, but I need to be able to update the value of a given key within the heap easily for my algorithm to function. WHat is the best way to achieve this in C++?

Comment: A priority queue is not an associative container. In fact, it isn't even a container; its an adapter. There are no "keys" and "values". There are only "values" who's comparator, default or otherwise, is used to establish the heap property on the underlying container used for the queue. There is nothing stopping you from making those values shared pointers or an otherwise-external-reference mechanism (with a proper comparator of course) and have the actual values stored in a real associative container somewhere else with indexed access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binary heaps (which are how priority queues are implemented in the C++ standard library) do not support arbitrary update-key operations. A common method if updates are infrequent is to extrinsically flag the original item as invalid, and reinsert the value with the new key; when an invalid value is popped, it is ignored.

The alternative is using a different PQ implementation which does support update-key, such as a binomial heap. Binomial heaps have the particular advantage of being manipulated by swinging pointers, instead of moving values. This streamlines the task of implementing operations like update-key and delete.

Comment: That's not true: binary heaps do allow key updates quite easily.  After an element of the heap is updated, you just need to ensure the heap-invariant still holds.  In short if the new key is smaller than its parent swap with it; if it is larger than a child; swap with it; finally: recurse.

Comment: The problem is not manipulating the element, but *finding* it. In order to change the key of an element given the element's identity, you need to either do an O(n) scan, or maintain backpointers for the elements in the heap. Either one is a serious hit to performance: the first asymptotic, the second practical.

Comment: Sure, you need to add backpointers.  I've done this before, and it's not exactly problematic - it's one extra integer in your heap elements; and one extra integer write for each element moved.  Most datastructures have the same limitation; this has nothing to do with binary heaps.  Removing an element from a linked list is O(1) - unless you need to find it in the list first.  Removing an element from a fibonnaci heap similarly requires knowing where it is, first.

Comment: Also, this isn't unusual or anything - anybody using a binary heap for dijkstra's algorithm *needs* to be able to reduce the distance to an element if a shorter path is found - and binary heaps are one of the simplest ways of doing so.

Comment: Hmm, I think I see where you're coming from - the binary heap implementation adapter used doesn't support backpointers, so from the perspective of `priority_queue`, this is true.  It's just a little misleading to say binary heaps in general don't support this.

Comment: That's a good point. (Your one about backpointers specifically. [Though the other points were good too. :-)]) For fib-heaps, though, your heap is often intrusive instead of extrusive, so there's no question of knowing where it is -- it's right *here*.

Comment: Specifically for Dijkstra's (or A*), I've often seen implementations that just re-insert the element for key reduction. That blows the theoretical complexity guarantees, but in common use cases I've seen, the time saved in backpointers makes up for the time spent processing the redundant elements.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40494/discussion-between-ben-and-eamon-nerbonne)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're take on [**Boost**](http://www.boost.org/) is, but I always consider a kind of almost standard library (some boost functionality has even ended up in standard library).  In any case, *if* you're ok with using boost, then [Boost.Heap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/heap.html) provides a priority queue with updatable priority.

Like most boost libraries, it's header-only, so there's no linker hassles to go through and it won't make your build system any more complex.  You can just `#include` it and use it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the ability to comment on your question, but here is my understanding.

Your mentioned *pairs*, and it sounds like you need the ability to change the priority from some function of your first element of the pair to your second element.

That is, you want to initially use FirstComparator below, but then switch to SecondComparator.

```
typedef std::pair<X, Y> MyPair;
struct FirstComparator 
{
    bool operator() (const MyPair& left, const MyPair& right) 
    {
        return left.first < right.first;
    }      
}

struct SecondComparator 
{
    bool operator() (const MyPair& left, const MyPair& right) 
    {
        return left.second < right.second;
    }      
}
```

Because `std::priority_queue` is a template that includes a sorting criterion (as your question mentioned), you can create a second container of a different type.  (I wrote less-than comparisons, so we have a min-heap.)

You will need to transfer the members into it.

```
std::priority_queue<MyPair, std::vector<MyPair>, FirstComparator> firstQueue;

// Populate and use firstQueue

// Now create an initially-empty queue sorting according to other criterion,
// and copy elements in.
std::priority_queue<MyPair, std::vector<MyPair>, SecondComparator> secondQueue;

// Use 'push' instead of 'emplace' for pre-C++11 code
while (! firstQueue.empty())
    secondQueue.emplace(firstQueue.pop());  

// Use secondQueue
```

An *alternative approach* is to use a single `std::vector`, and resort it with `std::sort` using different sorting criteria.  C++11 allows you to create named or anonymous lambda functions for establishing such sorting criteria on-the-fly.

Since your question specifically involved priority queues, I won't get into that unless you're specifically interested.